# Syntax error while saving postgresql server info in settings.py Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

I am trying to save Postgres server info using the book Django for professionals by WsVincent but I am getting a syntax error under Ports. This is what my code looks like:

```
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': 'postgres',
            'USER': 'postgres',
            'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
            'HOST': 'db',
            'PORT': 5432
        }
    }
```

The error that pops up is

```
    web_1  |     'PORT': 5432
    web_1  |           ^
    web_1  | SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

even when I add quotes around 5432 or a comma is still doesn't work.
Could someone help me please. Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

```
# If you are using postgres sql, then you have to install 'psycopg2' by using the command 'pip install psycopg2'.
# You also have to change the 'ENGINE' value of your database dictionary to 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '5432', # specify your port in quotes
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, you’re a Godsend